# Reading fault detail from WSCF blue generated WCF layer

Tags: c#, wcf

I generated a WCF layer using WSCF Blue.

My problem is that the detail of the handled FaultException on the client side is blank.

But in the Fiddler XML response I have a reponse from the service which has detail.

Anyone any ideas on why the detail is blank in the FaultException object?

I have added to the service behaviour in web.config includeExceptionDetailInFaults = true.
I have also added added this as an attribute on the WCF service implementation class.

Kind regards,

Brian

Comment: If you're at the beginning of your project I would strongly recommend not using WSCF Blue. It hasn't been maintained for quite a while.

Comment: Can you please evidence where WSCF blue is no longer supported or maintained?

Comment: http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/ - last release was on Fri Oct 14, 2011. also, I might be wrong here, but I think I read something from the author that it will no longer be developed.

Comment: I think the utility is still fit for purpose in creating a WCF layer from a .wsdl file. This is beside the point of not being able to read the detail of a FaultException from a WCF layer even though the response in fiddler shows the detail.